# Error: Cannot find module 'connect'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am kinda new to this server-stuff, and I am watching a video on youtube which explains is pretty well. I follow what he seems to be doing, and i installed 'connect' via npm locally in my project folder.

The structure looks like this:

```
 servertest
 |
 |-node_modules
 |-package.json
 |-package-lock.json
 |-server.js
```

Then I went on to require it in my server.js file like following:

```
var connect = require("connect");
```

But for some unknown reason, it spits out the following:

```
 module.js:540
 throw err;
 ^

 Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
 at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
 at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
 at [stdin]:3:15
 at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
 at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:38)
 at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
 at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
 at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:462:27)
```

Is there anyone who knows what I am doing wrong? (by the way, I have read on some other questions with answers already, but I can't really understand what they actually are doing to resolve the problem).

Also, I have added both express and connect to my json file:

```
 {   "name": "servertest",  
 "version": "1.0.0",   
 "description": "",  
 "main": "server.js",   
 "dependencies": {
 "connect": "^3.6.6",
 "express": "^4.16.3"   
  },
 "devDependencies": {}, 
 "scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  
  },
   "author": "",   
 "license": "ISC" 
  }
```

Comment: How exactly do you run the contents of server.js? Looking at your stack trace there's some heavy lifting going on.

Comment: @idmean Yeah, I've been thinking about it. Thought it might have something to do with it. I'm using the 'script' package for atom as a terminal. I'm literally just pressing **ctrl + alt + b** to build it.

Comment: Is there a smarter way to do it, @idmean?

Comment: What happens if you run this directly with node? Please try cd'ing into the "servertest" directory and run `node server.js`

Comment: you    are    a     legend     bro

Comment: oh my god i am so stupid xD It works, though ^^ My excuse is that i am a noob at this (for now)

Answer (score 1):

Are your sure `working directory` is `servertest` ?
And you have folder `servertest/connect`, if not please install module `connect`.

Comment: I have already recieved an answer to my question. @idmean came with the solution.